# XSLT: move from one context to other context nodes inside for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am writing an XSL transformation where I am not able to move to root and access other nodes inside for each.

Suppose I am inside the one context. I have a situation where I have to go to the outer node to get a value from there and return back to the same context.

Here is my XML file.

```
    <xml version=1.0>

    <abc>
     <parts>
            <part pno="10506">
              <pname>Land Before Time I</pname>
              <qoh>200</qoh>
              <price>19.99</price>
              <level>20</level>
            </part>
            …
      </parts>
       <orders>
            <order ono="1022" takenBy="1001" customer="2222">
              <receivedDate>1995-02-13</receivedDate>
              <shippedDate>1995-02-20</shippedDate>
              <items>
                <item>
                  <partNumber>10601</partNumber>
                  <quantity>1</quantity>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <partNumber>10701</partNumber>
                  <quantity>1</quantity>
                </item>
              </items>
         </order>

     .....
     </orders>
    </abc>
```

I am iterating inside the "item" tag  in xsl:for-each but I want to go inside the "part" tag and take a value and return back to the same context.

To be more detailed: I am filling up a table. My table has 4 columns:

- partname: I have to go to `<part>` to get the name. (This is where I got stuck)
- quantity : It's not a problem for me because it's a subelement of `<item>`.
- price: I face the same problem.
- total: It's easy.

Please help me in getting values for partname and price from the parts tag.

The following code is not working for me.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet>

        <table>
             <xsl:param name="param1" />

             <xsl:variable name="temp" select ="name(/*)"/>
               <xsl:for-each select=".//order[@ono=$param1]/items/item">
                     <tr>
          <td> <xsl:value-of select="$temp//part[@pno=partNumber]/pname"/>  </td>
          <td> <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/> </td>                                                       
          <td> <xsl:value-of select="$temp//part[@pno=partNumber]/price"/>  </td>
          <td> <xsl:value-of select="quantity*$temp//part[@pno=partNumber]/price"/>  </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </table>      




    <xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried googling but I couldn't get an exact solution for my problem. The code that I wrote throws some error. I tried by changing the select value of "temp" to root(.) but it's not working.

I just need a hint. I don't need the answer. Just a hint is enough for me.

I got stuck in this problem for the past 5 hours. Please reply and help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to refer to something relative to the current context from inside a predicate, you can use `current()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="param1" select="1022" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="//order[@ono=$param1]/items/item">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="//part[@pno=current()/partNumber]/pname"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="//part[@pno=current()/partNumber]/price"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="quantity * //part[@pno=current()/partNumber]/price"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A more efficient approach here, however, is to use keys. I've also cleaned up the XSLT a bit to make better use of templates and avoid repetition in the paths:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kPart" match="part" use="@pno" />

  <xsl:param name="param1" select="1022" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//order[@ono=$param1]/items/item" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="part" select="key('kPart', partNumber)" />
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$part/pname"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$part/price"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="quantity * $part/price"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Root is not `.`. Root is `/`. If you want any descendant of the root with element name "part" you use `//part`.

If you put `<xsl:template match="/">` before `<table>` and put `</xsl:template>` after `</table>`, then when the XML parser parses the document root, the XSL processor will produce your table element.

Your `xsl:stylesheet` open tag requires a couple of attributes. It should be `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">` for XSLT 1.0.

I think this little bit of information may be enough for you to get it working.

If you need to improve the efficiency, you should avoid `//` and use an `xsl:key` instead. You can find the definition, fundamentals, and simple example of [`xsl:key` in the XSL Transformations specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key).